# How to concatenate columns' name in new column if value =1 otherwise return 0 (python)

Tags: python, concatenation

Example data:

```
| alcoholism | diabites | | handicapped |  hypertensive |          new col        |
|  --------  | -------- | |  --------   |    --------   |     ----------------    |
|     1      |    0     | |     1       |       0       | alcoholism, handicapped |
|     0      |    1     | |     0       |       1       | diabites, hypertensive  |
|     0      |    1     | |     0       |       0       |          diabites       |
```

If any of the above columns has value = 1, then I need the new column to have the names of these columns only,
and if all are zero return no condition.

I had tried to do it with the below code:

```
problems = ['alcoholism', 'diabetes','hypertension','handicap']

m1 = df[problems].isin([1]) 
mask = m1 | (m1.loc[~m1.any(axis=1)])

df['sp_name'] = mask.mul(problems).apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i], axis=1)
```

But it returns the data with brackets like `[handicapped, alcoholism]`.
The issue is that I can't do value counts as the zero values show as empty `[]` and will not be plotted.

Comment: The brackets just mean it's a list. Do you mean you simply want one string? Why? And I don't understand what you mean about the plotting... Perhaps with a bit more context, we could help you achieve what you're after.

Comment: ...Do you have an issue with my edits? I only formatted your code and provided proofreading. Now your table is unreadable again. Also: already tried to convert what? To what? And what didn't work?

Comment: sorry for the miss i don't use this website alot. i already tried to convert it but it didn't work i have been looking the whole day searching for a way that can achieve it anyway if you can help i need to be able to do value_count for this column to show the count of whoever have these condition and to plot it in pie chart showing its percentage.

Comment: So you want the total number of people who have each condition? In this example you want something like `['alcoholism': 1, 'diabetes': 2, 'handicapped': 1, 'hypertensive': 1]`?

Comment: no i just need make the last column shows what person suffers from which will be the concatenated headers in that column later i will apply the value count of the people who suffers from the same codition

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand your ultimate goal, or how this will be useful in plotting, but all you're really missing is using [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to combine each list into the string you want. That said, the way you've gotten there involves unnecessary steps. First, multiply the DataFrame by its own column names:

```
df * df.columns
```

```
   alcoholism  diabetes  handicapped  hypertension
0  alcoholism            handicapped              
1              diabetes               hypertension
2              diabetes
```

Then you can `apply` the same as you did:

```
(df * df.columns).apply(lambda row: [i for i in row if i], axis=1)
```

```
0    [alcoholism, handicapped]
1     [diabetes, hypertension]
2                   [diabetes]
dtype: object
```

Then you just need to include a string `join` in the function you supply to `apply`. Here's a complete example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'alcoholism': [1, 0, 0],
    'diabetes': [0, 1, 1],
    'handicapped': [1, 0, 0],
    'hypertension': [0, 1, 0],
})

df['new_col'] = (
    (df * df.columns)
    .apply(lambda row: ', '.join([i for i in row if i]), axis=1)
)

print(df)
```

```
   alcoholism  diabetes  handicapped  hypertension                  new_col
0           1         0            1             0  alcoholism, handicapped
1           0         1            0             1   diabetes, hypertension
2           0         1            0             0                 diabetes
```

Answer (score -1):

```
df['new_col'] = df.iloc[:, :-1].dot(df.add_suffix(",").columns[:-1]).str[:-1]
```

i already found this solution helpful for me

Comment: This doesn't work properly. On your sample data, the middle person is listed as just diabetes instead of diabetes and hypertension.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).